# Dynamically creating an input field with disabled = true is setting null values to zero

Tags: javascript, disabled-input

I have a timesheet table.  At the bottom of the table there is a button which allows me to add a row.  Understandably, all the cells in the new row start off empty.  The JavaScript uses:

```
txtFld.setAttribute('value', '');
```

to do so.

However, in some situations I want some of the new fields to show up but be disabled so I (in those situations) add in:

```
txtFld.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

The problem is that, when doing this, after submission, when the table re-renders itself, all those empty values show up as zeroes instead of empty strings.  As far as calculations go, that's fine, but I don't want rows of zeroes. I want empty cells. If I take out the disabled part, it works fine.

I've temporarily remedied this by, instead of using disabled, using readonly, which seems to give me the desired results.  The only problem is that, while the text field remains non-editable, the user CAN place the cursor inside the box. I want the cleaner, "can't even click in here" that the disabled gives me.

Any thoughts on why the disabled feature is doing this and how I can use disabled without the resulting row of zeroes?

For the record, I've mixed and matched every combination of:

```
txtFld.setAttribute('value','');
txt.setAttribute('value', null);
txtFld.value = '';
txtFld.value = null;
```

with

```
txtFld.setAttribute('disabled');
txtFld.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
txtFld.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
txtFld.disabled = 'true';
txtFld.disabled = 'disabled';
```

that I can think of with the same results (or worse) every time.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to use `.setAttribute()` to manipulate properties of DOM nodex.  `txtField.value = null` or `txtFld.disabled = true` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When a field is disabled, it's not included in the form parameters sent to the server.

In new browsers (IE11+, and pretty much everything else) you can use CSS to disable pointer events on the element:

```
txtFld.readonly = true;
txtFld.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

That'll make the element simply not respond to any clicks. ([Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/4x8yY/)) Because it's not disabled, a form POST *will* send the empty field to the server.

You should disable fields by setting the "disabled" property of their DOM nodes to `true` (the boolean constant, not the string).

```
txtFld.disabled = true; // disables field
txtFld.disabled = false; // enables field
```

The "disabled" property is treated as a boolean, so setting it to *any* string value (other than the empty string) will set it to `true`:

```
txtFld.disabled = "false"; // disables field
```

---

Another thing you can do to exploit the real `disabled` browser behavior *and* have empty parameters posted to the server is to use pairs of inputs:

```
<input type=text name=whatever data-companion=whatever-c> <!-- visible input -->
<input type=hidden name=whatever id=whatever-c> <!-- invisible input -->
```

Now whenever you *enable* the text field, you *disable* the hidden input, and vice-versa.  That way there's always something posted.

Comment: I added in the txtFld.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; with no results.  I can still click within the input field.  It still won't let me type anything, but I can place the blinking cursor in there.

Comment: @ReverendDovie what browser are you using?  It works in up-to-date Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: Sadly, I'm forced to do this in IE9.

Comment: @ReverendDovie OK well as I said it only works in IE11.  The other thing you can do is to pair the inputs with companion hidden input fields.  I'll extend the answer.